# SQLite + windsor.castle version issue

Tags: sqlite, castle-windsor, s#arp-architecture

I am trying to run some integration test and use this:

```
public class ServiceLocatorInitializer
{
public static void Init()
{
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Register(
        Component
        .For(typeof(IEntityDuplicateChecker))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(EntityDuplicateChecker))
        .Named("entityDuplicateChecker"));

    container.Register(
        Component.For(typeof(ISessionFactoryKeyProvider))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
        .Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
}
}
```

plus this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
      <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;</property>
        <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

I have a reference to Castle.Windsor version 3.1.0.0 but get this error:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

Not sure what the reason is and how to overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WindsorServiceLocator is build against an older version of Castle and has not been updated.

You need to add a BindingRedirect in the App.Config of your test project, you should be able to add them by opening the Nuget Package Manager Console in visual studio, select the test project and run

```
Add-BindingRedirect
```

Check the App.Config and you should now have binding redirects for the assemblies.

Comment: I think i tried this already. Will check later again. Thanks Seif!

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle has a dependency on Castle as it uses DynamicProxy as its proxy factory. That issue was resolved with NHibernate 3.2 which has its own proxy factory and doesn't depend on Castle. If possible, upgrade NHibernate to at least 3.2 and remove the proxyfactory configuration from your nhibernate config file.

Comment: Thanks my nhibernate.dll version is 3.3.1.4000 and I have remove the proxyfactory line. Problem persists ...

Comment: any other 3rd party library with a dependency to Castle Windsor?